# 2 or 3 Finger Drag in Windows 10?

Tags: laptop, mouse, touchpad, pan, finger

I got a new MSI GS65 laptop with a precision trackpad.

I really want to do a click and drag option with for Photoshop and C4D, ideally if I click the space bar in photoshop and maybe use 2 or 3 fingers to drag, I want to pan.  Or if I use the 1 key in c4D and 2 or 3 fingers to drag, I would pan again.  But I can't seem to find a solution to this!!

Physically clicking the trackpad is difficult because the MSI's click is so damn hard, my fingers are going to be hurting after a few hours of work.  And a mouse is not an option because I'm commuting by train when I use my laptop.

Any help is greatly appreciated!! :)

Comment: I've always used tap and drag, just double tap like when you double click but don't lift the finger after the second tap. Now it's in drag-and-drop mode and you can drag the object anywhere

Comment: can you also describe how do you perform other commands that need holding mouse button. For example in Photoshop, rectangular selection tool ('m') - can you use it normally?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the "ELAN Input Device for WDF" driver.

Comment: Some explanation as to why this is the solution would go a long way towards improving this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly it is hard to make mouse clicks with your touchpad?
I am not sure but it seems you should find a way to make mouse clicks comfortably 
first. You can use Autohotkey to bind a key to left mouse button.
Download page:
https://www.autohotkey.com/download/1.1/
(download last version installer, e.g. AutoHotkey_1.1.29.01_setup.exe)

Then you make a script and save it with `.ahk` extesion.
For example to bind `x` key to mouse click in Photoshop use such script:

```
#If winActive("ahk_exe Photoshop.exe")
x::Lbutton
```

Save it e.g. as `psd.ahk` and run (Autohotkey must be installed of course). Now you can click with the `x` key on the keyboard. 
And to pan in Photoshop you first select the hand tool with "h" and then 
hold `x` and drag. Hope this helps.